# Ruby minus operator with ActiveRecord objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, benchmarking

Can you explain pls, how's Ruby's minus operator working? Not just trivial case like 5 - 2.
A bit more complex – we have 2 arrays with ActiveRecord objects:
Array A = `User.where(...)`, Array B = `User.where(...)`, I wanna make A - B, how is it working? Is it just comparing objects IDs, or all attributes, or smth else?

Comment: 1. Ruby 'operators' are just methods. 2. `User.where(...)` doesn't return an array, but relation.

Comment: @MarekLipka: not all operators are methods, but most are, yes `-` included.

Comment: @MarekLipka Guys, it's doesn't matter what exactly `where` returns, I mean, if we took 2 arrays with AR objects: A = [u.find(1), u.find(2)], B = [u.find(2), u.find(3)]. How's minus method will be working `under the hood`?

Comment: @Joe from the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-2D): _"It compares elements using their `hash` and `eql?` methods for efficiency"_, so it depends on how your objects implement these methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it just comparing objects IDs?

Type and ID, yes.

```
pry(main)> show-source User#eql?

From: /Users/sergio/.gem/ruby/2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/core.rb @ line 420:
Owner: ActiveRecord::Core
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 6

def ==(comparison_object)
  super ||
    comparison_object.instance_of?(self.class) &&
    !id.nil? &&
    comparison_object.id == id
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm searching for. Sry, but I can't upvote ur answer :(

Comment: That From/Owner/Visibility/LOC output looks interesting – do you have a tool to extract certain methods?

Comment: @Stefan: huh? That's vanilla pry. `show-source User.new.==`. Doesn't work too well on native/C methods, though.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev TIL 

Comment: @Stefan: your life will now change forever. This tool helped me so many times. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev what do you mean doesn't work too well on native C methods? `show-source Object.==` outputs  `From: object.c (C Method):
Owner: Module
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 6` and the C function body

Comment: @engineersmnky: I just can't be bothered to do `gem-install pry-doc` (every time I change ruby version). ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Just for additional details from Sergio's answer:

I narrowed down what the `-` method (operator) does on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, because I got curious as well myself:

### Rails 5:

#### Traceback:

```
# rails console (pry-rails)
users_a = User.where(...)
users_b = User.where(...)

puts users_a.class
# => `User::ActiveRecord_Relation`

show-source users_a.-

# From: /Users/jrpolidario/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb @ line 41:
# Owner: ActiveRecord::Delegation
# Visibility: public
# Number of lines: 4
#
# delegate :to_xml, :encode_with, :length, :each, :uniq, :join,
#          :[], :&, :|, :+, :-, :sample, :reverse, :rotate, :compact, :in_groups, :in_groups_of,
#          :to_sentence, :to_formatted_s, :as_json,
#          :shuffle, :split, :slice, :index, :rindex, to: :records

# since the `-` method as seen above is delegated to #records, let's see what the return type is the return value of `#records` is, of which is supposed to respond to the `-` operator.

puts users_a.records.class
# => Array

# ...because it's an Array type, then let's see if the Array type responds to the delegated `-` method.

show-source users_a.records.-

# From: array.c (C Method):
# Owner: Array
# Visibility: public
# Number of lines: 17
# 
# static VALUE
# rb_ary_diff(VALUE ary1, VALUE ary2)
# {
#     VALUE ary3;
#     VALUE hash;
#     long i;
# 
#     hash = ary_make_hash(to_ary(ary2));
#     ary3 = rb_ary_new();
# 
#     for (i=0; i<RARRAY_LEN(ary1); i++) {
#   if (st_lookup(rb_hash_tbl_raw(hash), RARRAY_AREF(ary1, i), 0)) continue;
#   rb_ary_push(ary3, rb_ary_elt(ary1, i));
#     }
#     ary_recycle_hash(hash);
#     return ary3;
# }
```

... which just simply means, I quote from [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-2D)

> Returns a new array that is a copy of the original array, removing any items that also appear in other_ary. The order is preserved from the original array.

### Rails 4

P.S. I also tried tracing this in rails 4.2, and `show-source users_a.-` does not show any method, which meant that it makes use of `method_missing` (therefore also meant that there has been changes between 4 and 5 with regards to this), and then, tracing further, I ended up with below:

#### Traceback:

```
[127, 136] in /Users/jrpolidario/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb
   127: 
   128:     def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
   129:       if @klass.respond_to?(method)
   130:         scoping { @klass.public_send(method, *args, &block) }
   131:       elsif array_delegable?(method)
=> 132:         to_a.public_send(method, *args, &block)
   133:       elsif arel.respond_to?(method)
   134:         arel.public_send(method, *args, &block)
   135:       else
   136:         super
```

... which as you could see `.to_a` is called on the `ActiveRecord::Relation` object which means that it becomes an array, and then `method` (which is `'-'`) is called on that Array object, which also means in the end it also calls the `Array#-` method same in Rails 5 above.